# What is difference between Managed and Advanced workflow in Expo cli

Tags: react-native, expo

Recently I try to create new React native app with Expo-cli with this command  `expo init` and after choosing template (I choose `blank template`) I see new option that say choose your workflow :

```
? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
? Choose which workflow to use: (Use arrow keys)
> managed (default)
  Build your app with JavaScript with Expo APIs.
  advanced (experimental �)
  Build your app with JavaScript with Expo APIs and custom native modules.
```

I try to search and can't find anything that helps me. Is it mean's that I can use some node modules that before it I can't use them because Expo doesn't support them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `advanced` app, It is just like `react-native init`, But you will be also getting Expo API's. before this, if we had to write native modules in expo apps, we had to eject our apps.

Now expo provides a way in which we already start with an ejected app for more stability.

For more info, you can check this 
https://blog.expo.io/expokit-2019-1e5cb02106f8